# Pass data between steps in Airflow from EMR job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, airflow, message-passing

In airflow, I am executing a jar using EmrCreateJobFlowOperator on EMR cluster. This job writes some data on S3 and I want to pass this S3 path to the next step in the airflow dag as this path would be dynamic for every run.

What I think is that XCom are not useful in this scenario as my job is Java based and it is simply executed as a jar on EMR. Also, I do not want to make my Java code airflow specific as I want to use it separately as well.

Any solutions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think XCom is your only option. When you run EmrCreateJobFlowOperator, it needs to be followed by EmrJobFlowSensor. You can override the sensor with your own class I guess and retrieve the s3 path where the data is written (i guess you can return it to the sensor in some status metadata) - then your custom senser can push the data to xcom and the next operator with dependency on the sensor) can read that s3 path from the xcom.

Comment: How and where to write data from the Java code i.e. S3 path? Also, is there any way I can get the EMR cluster ID inside my Java code and in the next step in airflow DAG? Maybe I can use that as a prefix in S3 path.

Comment: I Don't know details about Java code. You need to somehow pass the data you want in results of the job (which I guess is somewhat possible to add stuff as metadata) that you can see when the job completes.

Answer (score 0):

**For S3 path** you can use xcom to pass it to next step or either make a hashed/prefixed version of actual name as a path so that it can be accessed afterwards.

**For retieving cluster** When using EmrCreateJobFlowOperator to create a job, you can access returned object's `output`key to get jobflow_id. This will be the cluster_id as well

```
   job_flow_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='create_job_flow',
    )

   job_sensor = EmrJobFlowSensor(
    task_id='check_job_flow',
    job_flow_id=job_flow_creator.output,
       aws_conn_id='aws_default',
)
```